# using linq select highest value elements from a container such that they add to x

Tags: c#, linq, list, tuples

I have a list of 3-sized tuple -- two of the items being data and one being the 'value' of that data.

I want to get the highest value elements possible that fit a certain total of values.

Comment: This isn't a pop quiz. I have code with the specifications I describe and wanted to see if someone was capable of expressing the same thing in linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Max` in Linq:

```
var tuples = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>()
{
    new Tuple<string, string, int>("a.1", "a.2", 50),
    new Tuple<string, string, int>("b.1", "b.2", 70),
    new Tuple<string, string, int>("c.1", "c.2", 40),
};
var matches = GetHighestTuples(tuples, 150); // returns 50 and 70
```

**UPDATE: Added function to filter list of tuples getting fewest number of tuples required to be less than or equal to a given maximum value as described in the comments below.**

To accomplish this, you have to first sort them in descending order by the third value, then keep a running total until you reach the desired sum while persisting the original tuple value so that once the desired running total is reached, you can transform back to return only the original tuples as described.

```
    public List<Tuple<string, string, int>> GetHighestTuples(List<Tuple<string, string, int>> tuples, int maxSum)
    {
        int runningTotal = 0;
        var results = tuples
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.Item3)
            .Select(t => new
                {
                    Item = t,
                    RunningTotal = (runningTotal += t.Item3)
                })
            .Where(t => t.RunningTotal <= maxSum)
            .Select(t => t.Item)
            .ToList();
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: @2c2c Please feel free to upvote an answer if it helped you and accept it if it solved your question. This helps others to know which answers may have helped and if any solved your question. It also increases your reputation.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for. In the code you show for example, say I would maybe want the fewest amount of elements that add to (without going over) say 200 (50+70+40 = 160, so all of them), 150 (exclude 40), 115 (exclude 50), 80 (just 70). I suppose it's hard to express because its dependent on the other elements that compose the list. Regardless I don't see anyone answering this, have an upvote sir

Comment: Now I see what you're looking for. I'll see what I can do.